# Кириллица в pdf отчетах Jasperreports

Tags: java, pdf, windows-server-2012, jasperreports

В j2ee с помощью Jasperreports создаются отчеты. Выставлен шрифт arial, на **локальной** машине(Tomcat 9, Windows 7) отчеты в pdf формируются **корректно**, а при развертывании на сервере (Tomcat 9, MS-Server 2012) русские символы не воспроизводятся. Код

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
reportFileName = URLEncoder.encode(reportFileName, "UTF8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=\"utf-8'" + reportFileName + "." + extension + "\"");  
JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
pdfExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
pdfExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setCreatingBatchModeBookmarks(true);              
pdfExporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
pdfExporter.exportReport();
```

faces-config.xml

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>ru</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

Кто-либо сталкивался?

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось просто. При развертывании Tomcat на сервере отсутствовала папка temp. Создал вручную, и все заработало. Для Linux, при запуске Tomcat не под системной учеткой, требуется проверить права доступа к этой папке.